# Image to process has wrong gray value type (HALCON error code: 9001)

Tags: computer-vision, halcon, hdevelop

i am trying to make a calibration program for machine vision with Halcon.
What i am doing is i use the image acquisition assistant to connect to my external camera and then i insert the generated code for the acquisition of a picture. Then i am using find_calib_object and i get the following error : Image to process has wrong gray value type (HALCON error code: 9001)
This is the picture i've taken:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcycP.png)

My question is how to fix this error and how to make the picture rgb

This is my code:
write_string(WindowHandle, 'Generating a position and sending it to the robot...')
* Using procedure to generate the position and send the robot

```
PositionGeneration (Socket, WindowHandle, TupleWithPositions)

* Image Acquisition 01: Code generated by Image Acquisition 01
open_framegrabber ('GenICamTL', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'default', -1, 'default', -1, 'false', 'default', 'Zivid_DEV_21513D73', 0, -1, AcqHandle)
grab_image_start (AcqHandle, -1)
grab_image_async (Image, AcqHandle, -1)
* Image Acquisition 01: Do something
close_framegrabber (AcqHandle)


dev_display (Image)

* Saving the picture
```

- ```
  write_image (Image, 'png none', 0, 'Image'+I)
  ```

  find_calib_object (Image, CalibDataID, 0, 0, I, 'alpha', 0.2)

  get_calib_data_observ_contours (Caltab, CalibDataID, 'caltab', 0, 0, I)

  get_calib_data_observ_points (CalibDataID, 0, 0, I, Row, Column, Index, Pose)

  dev_set_color ('green')
  dev_display(Image)
  dev_display (Caltab)

  tuple_number (TupleWithPositions, PoseCoordinates)
  X := PoseCoordinates[0]
  Y := PoseCoordinates[1]
  Z := PoseCoordinates[2]
  A := PoseCoordinates[3]
  B := PoseCoordinates[4]
  C := PoseCoordinates[5]

  create_pose (X, Y, Z, A, B, C, 'Rp+T', 'abg', 'point', Pose)
  set_calib_data (CalibDataID, 'tool', I, 'tool_in_base_pose', Pose)

I've tried to change the parameters of the camera but nothing has helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Why do you have a cursor on the image if this is taken by the camera?
2. Your *.png file has 3 channels which are identical.

If you have an RGB camera, you need to set the open_framegrabber parameters "colorspace" and "bitsperchannel" to correct values.

Comment: I took a screenshot of the photo from the graphics window :D and thank you i will look into it